# Using A Button To Change Pages InXCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm making an app in xcode for iphone with multiple pages. How can I change to a different page in the app by clicking a button?

Comment: Look up UINavigationController.

Comment: When you say 'pages' you mean multiple screens (like List of Contacts, Contact Details are 2 separate screens in the default Contact app for iPhone) or is it like pages of a book, because there's something called PageViewController in IOS that does that.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way, as Aaron mentioned, is to embed your view controller inside a Navigation Controller. If you are using storyboard, then select your view controller on the storyboard, and click menu item Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. And for trying how navigation will work, add a push segue from your login button on the login view controller to another view controller (your new 'page' where you want to navigate to will be another view controller on the storyboard) by Control + 
clicking + dragging from the button over to the other view controller.

You can also navigate to another view controller programmatically without the segue. On the method that's called on Login button click, you can call another view controller (new 'page') like this:

```
// Create a new view controller
UIViewController *myController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
// If you have the view controller defined in the storyboard, and you have give it a Storyboard Id, let's say "MyViewController", you can get it like this:
// UIViewController *myController = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

// Push/Navigate to the new view controller
[self.navigationController pushNavigationController:myController animated:YES];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
UIViewController *viewControllerYouWant = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:viewControllerYouWant];
```

If you touch the login button you go to the other view. And if you are on the other view use the same code just including the viewcontroller you want to go.